# Making HTML inputs the same length using a CSS percentage based layout

Tags: html, css

Given that `<select>` and `<textarea>` display as two different widths if both set to `width: 50%` is there any way to make them the same width whilst using a percentage based layout?

An example can be seen here - http://jsfiddle.net/KfQ5b/

Even though both are set to `width:50%` they display at slightly different lengths, the biggest difference is probably in IE7 (which is the browser of choice for my intended user base)

**EDIT**

I have applied Petah's suggestion of box-sizing which works for most other browsers but IE7 won't play ball.

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see what you're trying to do? If you can't allow access to your server, you can make a temporary example at jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Kyle, done, thanks for introducing me to jsfiddle.net - http://jsfiddle.net/KfQ5b/

Comment: you're welcome. What do you mean by "line up?" Do you mean "make the same width?"

Comment: @Kyle: I guess so actually, sorry, bad choice of words, I will edit again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `box-sizing`
Although I don't know if IE will like it

```
textarea, select {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/KfQ5b/6/

Its to do with the border making the textarea 1px bigger than the select. Play around with -1px margins and such to see if that works. (I would but I don't have IE7)

Comment: IE doesn't like it - works perfectly in the other browsers though.  Going to research shivving IE7 to play nice!